# Fabric js: overriding toSVG method to add custom attribute into svg output

Tags: svg, fabricjs

I am trying to add attribute into my SVG output using fabric.js library.
Here is my code:

```js
objectGlobal = new fabric.Rect({
        // here are some Rect attributes such as height width etc
        room_id: counter
    });
    objectGlobal.toSVG = (function(toSVG) {
        return function() {
            console.log("overriden to svg");
            return fabric.util.object.extend(toSVG.call(this), {
                room_id: this.room_id
            });
        };
    })(objectGlobal.toSVG);

    canvas.add(objectGlobal);
```

I got "overriden to svg" in my console, but my SVG output does not contain room_id attribute. 
Here is the SVG output:

```js
<rect x="-93.5" y="-49.5" rx="0" ry="0" width="187" height="99" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(229,229,229); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(318 160)"/>
```